# CS0176 Compiler error. What does it mean an how do I solve it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, compiler-errors

Im trying to retrieve data from my database with Linq in ASP.NET MVC. but when I call the method in a different class, I get the compiler error code CS0176:"Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

How I call the method:

```
public JsonResult RetrieveDataTable()
    {
        DatabaseHandler.DatabaseHandler dataName = new DatabaseHandler.DatabaseHandler();
        var dataListAssets = dataName.GetDisciplines();

        return Json(dataListAssets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return null;
    }
```

How the Method Looks like:

```
public static List<DisciplineVM2> GetDisciplines()
    {
        using (var db = new SPIESimpel_DEVEntities())
        {
            return db.tbl_Disciplines
              .Select((x) => new DisciplineVM2() { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name })
              .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Does someone see whats wrong and can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you are trying to access a static method `GetDisciplines` from an object instance. You should instead access it using the class name.

In your case, it would be:

```
var dataListAssets = DatabaseHandler.DatabaseHandler.GetDisciplines();
```